# VBA error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set (Excel 2013)

Tags: vba, excel

We're starting to test Excel 2013 at work and I'm experiencing strange behaviour with error code 91 (that did not occur in Excel 2007). There are two unusual behaviours;

1. Any time I modify a Range the `Err.Number` is set to 91, even in the most simple macro.
2. The macro will still function correctly, with the error not being thrown. E.g.

```
Sub Example1()
    On Error Goto DisplayError
    Range("A1").Clear   'Sets Err.Number to 91
    Exit Sub

DisplayError:
    Msgbox Err.Description   'Macro doesn't make it here
End Sub
```

Or when I explicitly declare a Range,

```
Sub Example2()
    Dim MyRange as Range
    Set MyRange = Range("A1")

    On Error Goto DisplayError
    With MyRange
        .Clear   'Sets Err.Number to 91
    End With
    Exit Sub

DisplayError:
    Msgbox Err.Description   'Macro doesn't make it here
End Sub
```

In both of these examples the macro will function correctly, and cell `A1` will be cleared without any error messages. `Err.Number` will be set to 91, while `DisplayError` is not called. The exact same methods will work in Office 2007 without setting `Err.Number` to 91.

Please note that reading from a Range does not change the `Err.Number`, e.g.

```
MyString = Range("A1").Value
```

Works fine and does not change the `Err.Number`.

If anyone can explain what's going on here that would be super.

**Edit:** Exact, tested code below.

```
Sub Example1()
   On Error Goto DisplayError
   MsgBox Err.Number   'Displays "0"
   Range("A1").Clear
   MsgBox Err.Number   'Displays "91"
   Exit Sub

DisplayError:
   Msgbox Err.Description   'Macro doesn't make it here
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not 91 before the call?

Comment: @paxdiablo: I'm absolutely sure. I have checked and cleared the error several times throughout a more complex macro to make sure the behaviour is as I mentioned above.

Comment: Then I'm at a loss since this seems to break the 'on error resume, with manual checking of err' paradigm. You'll have to wait for someone more knowledgable, as much as it galls me to say so :-)

Comment: Can't replicate here.  Maybe you can explain in more detail exactly what you're doing. For example why do you think the error number has been set to 91?  How are you checking that?

Comment: Any event handlers hooked up to (eg) worksheet_change ?

Comment: @Tim Williams: I've sandwiched lines I want to test between "Err.Clear" and "Msgbox Err.Number", and it's very clear where the offending lines are.

Comment: @Tim Williams: There are no event handlers on Worksheet_Change.  To test, I created a brand new workbook in a freshly opened instance of Excel, add-ins disabled, used the simplest code possible (as above), and checked where Err.Number changed step by step.

Comment: Still can't replicate.  Can you post the *exact* code you're using which shows the messagebox with the Error ?

Comment: @Tim Williams: It is the same as above, just with messageboxes either side.

Comment: @Tim Williams: Sorry pressed enter by mistake. 
Sub Example1()
   On Error GoTo DisplayError
   MsgBox Err.Number   'Msgbox displays "0"
   Range("A1").Clear
   MsgBox Err.Number   'Msgbox displays "91"
   Exit Sub

DisplayError:
   MsgBox Err.Description   'Macro doesn't make it here
End Sub

Comment: Using that exact code I'm not seeing any error - zero both times. 32-bit XL2013 on Win7 64-bit

Comment: @Tim Williams: I have found the general cause of the error, just need to figure out precisely which add-in is causing it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it appears that leaving add-ins disabled was insufficient to stop them from meddling.  I found running "excel /automation" disabled whatever is causing the issue, and the error no longer occurs.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out. Just starting to test Excel 2013 myself and hoping for no gotchas.